# Cant place item according to device's screen height

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am trying to add a child at the bottom of the screen.

I am using `stage.stageHeight`, but it doesn't seem to be able to get the height of the device properly.
It is leaving a very wide gap between the child (`s6`) and the bottom of the screen.

Code:

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onadded);
function onadded (event:Event):void{
    addChild(s6);
    s6.y = stage.stageHeight - s6.height;
    s6.width = width - 20;
    s6.x = stage.x+10;
}
```

Edit:

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onadded);
 function onadded (event:Event):void{




            addChild(s7);
            s7.width = stage.stageWidth;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            addChild(s6);
            trace(stage.fullScreenWidth);
            trace(stage.fullScreenHeight);
            s6.y = stage.fullScreenHeight - s6.height;
            s6.width = width - 20;
            s6.x = stage.x+10;
            s6.account.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoTomyaccount);
            s6.automatch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAAA);
               s6.search.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoTosearchpage);


                s7.myaccount.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoTomyaccount);
                s7.autmatch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAAA);

             s7.sssearch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoTosearchpage);


             }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the screen resolution property and use them in your code.

I have done one example like this and it varies on different screen resolutions.

```
var screenWidth:int = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
var screenHeight:int = Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
this.width= screenWidth - (screenWidth / 2);  
this.height=screenHeight - 200;
```

Hope it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `fullScreenHeight` instead of `stageHeight`: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#fullScreenHeight

This is very true especially when working with mobile devices. `stageHeight` and `stageWidth` are not very reliable then.

You may also want to wait for RESIZE event which will occur shot after your app initialized, and then you can again use `stageHeight` instead.

Comment: I just tried stage.fullScreenHeight, but my buttons disappeared...its not even on the displayed area for some reason, i tried this on my phone.

Comment: Just trace the `height` and `fullScreenHeight` properties, and show them here, as well as your phone resolution.

Comment: ok will do thanks, cos at the moment i run it on the flash debugger, it has no problem at all, but when it is on the phone... it disappears

Comment: I traced the fullscreenwidth and height it is 720,439(these height and width is from my flash debugger from my computer), i believe my phone's resolution is 720 x 1280, it is a note2. I did s6.y = stage.fullScreenHeight - s6.height; but the buttons(s6) they do not show up on screen. I placed the whole set of code up there in the edit.

Comment: If you are trying to develop for a device, you should use deploying on device directly and testing there. Check what's happening on your device, not on your computer.

Comment: You are actually doing: `s6.y = stage.fullScreenHeight;`, and it's normal that it's not visible, as it's out of the screen...

Comment: That was a copy and pasted mistake i did s6.y = stage.fullScreenHeight - s6.height;

Comment: I have turned to the last resort to get some insight, i started plugging in random int for the height of the buttons, i tried s6.y = flash.system.Capabilities.screenResolutionX - 200; and they started appearing on the screen. But i looked at Flash, the height of hte buttons are only 47.

Comment: When i do stage.fullScreenHeight then i can't see the buttons, when i do stage.stageHeight even after resizing with stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, updateSize); the buttons are way up with large gaps underneath them, i tried 
   s6.y = stage.fullScreenHeight - s6.height*2; and still cant see the buttons.

Comment: The phone seems to think its a lot bigger than it is, because i tried setting the width of the buttons as fullscreenWidth. And it only displays around a 20th of the buttons, as it became so wide.

Comment: It seems like it is setting the stageheight on my phone as the stageheight in flash pro.

Comment: Just do a simple `trace (stage.fullScreenHeight);` and see what it's printing, along with `stage.stageHeight;`....

Comment: I tried to debug via USB with my phone in, but everytime it publishes til the last 5 seconds it freezes there. I researched it, seems like quite a lot of people have the same issue with samsung too

Comment: I tested it again, the stage width and height proportion is not the one from the screen, it is the one set in flash pro.....

Comment: You mean doing this? stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE; I did that, but when i do stage.stageWidth, what it does is, it kept the proportion of the stage from Flash Pro(properties) and then it set the width to the width of the screen, but it keeps the proportion from flash pro, and set the height according to the height from that(flash Prop stage).

Comment: And if i do fullScreenWidth, it became Massive, and i tried plugging my phone in and debug via USB it freezes at last 5 second, i tried plugging in my Table samsung note 8 and the Adobe Air says cant not connect to IP...